# Shortest path problem with certain conditions

Tags: python, shortest-path

I have been searching for a shortest path algorithm with some conditions for 2 days but I'm not finding it. The algorithm should take 3 parameters, a beginning point, an ending point, a graph and should return the minimum time used to go from beginning point to ending point. But Djikstra's algorithm can't be used I think because I want the algorithm to use waiting nodes. Could someone give me some advice ?

PS: Sorry for my English I'm French :/ 
    [Illustration to my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHFoA.jpg)

[image]

Comment: add the wait time to all edges originating from a vertex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split each node with an internal delay into an input and output node, pictured blue and red, with a connection between them and use Dijkstra's algorithm:
[image: Graph]

Comment: Thanks a lot it functionned :)